# How to convert coordinates in a left-handed graph to a right-handed graph

Tags: graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

I have the following coordinates which describe points on a left-handed graph and I need to convert the graph to be right-handed instead:

> $(0,0), (21,56), (38,0), (51, 35), (-5, 38)$

Is it as simple as multiplying the $x$ coordinates by $-1$? Or is there a translation or something more complex involved too?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is a "left-handed graph" and "right-handed graph"?  I guess you mean whether or not the positive half of the $x$-axis is pointed to the left or right?

Comment: Yeah exactly, it needs flipping somehow

Comment: I don't know, I'm still not sure what you're after, but if you just want to reflect your graph through the $y$-axis, then multiplying each $x$-coordinate by $-1$ will do that (but this won't change which direction the $x$-axis points in).

Answer (score 0):

The fully correct solution is to use a change of basis matrix to construct a similarity transform as follows:

```
// Start with identity
changeOfBasis = matrix.identity

// Construct the basis which represents the difference between the two
// spaces. For a typical left/right handed space, the forward vector is
// inverted. Note that this is not well defined though, as there are many
// possible bases for left and right handed systems.
changeOfBasis[2,2] = -1;

// Apply the similarity transform.
newValue = changeOfBasis * value * changeOfBasis.inverse
```

Note that in this case, the inverse is the change of basis, so this can be simplified to:

```
newValue = changeOfBasis * value * changeOfBasis
```

Which can be further simplified further to 6 multiplies by -1. Note that this transform is fully general and works for both vectors and matrices (unlike the simple "invert Z" solution).